# How remove empty tags in Regex?

Tags: regex

I want to delete some empty tags, for example `<A/>`, `<B/>`, `<C/>`,....

How to remove these tags using Regex?

Comment: By empty tags you mean `<A></A>` not simply `</A>`?

Comment: i want to remove this type: <A/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this regex:

```
<[^>]+\/>
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL3wI5/2)**

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex1 = "<([a-zA-Z0-9-\\_]*)[^>]*/>";
        final String regex2 = "<([a-zA-Z0-9-\\_]*)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>";

        String xmlString = " <xml><A>bla</A><B></B><B/><D><E><G><H/></G></E><F></F></D></xml>";

        System.out.println(xmlString);

        final Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
        final Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);

        Matcher matcher1;
        Matcher matcher2;
        do {
            xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll(regex1, "").replaceAll(regex2, "");
            matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(xmlString);
            matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(xmlString);
        } while (matcher1.find() || matcher2.find());

        System.out.println(xmlString);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
<xml>
    <A>bla</A>
    <B></B>
    <B/>
    <D>
        <E>
            <G>
                <H/>
            </G>
        </E>
        <F></F>
    </D>
</xml>

<xml>
    <A>bla</A>
</xml>
```

[Online demo here](http://tpcg.io/qmeJOC)

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
/<[^\/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+>/
```

Comment: While this regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.